# How to rename or move a file in Google Cloud Storage (PHP API)

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-api-php-client

I am currently trying to rename and/or move a cloud storage file to another name/position, but I can't get it to work. I am using https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client as client, the uploads works fine with:

```
...
$storageService = new \Google_Service_Storage( $client )
$file = new \Google_Service_Storage_StorageObject()
$file->setName( 'test.txt' );
$storageService->objects->insert(
   $bucketName,
    $file,
    array(
        'name'          => $filename,
        'data'          => file_get_contents( $somefile )
    )
);
...
```

So I have tried to change a filename by the $storageObject->objects->update() method, but I cannot find any documentation on this. I used $storageService->objects->get( $bucketName, $fileName ) to get a specific file I wanted to rename (with $file->setName()), but it seems I just cannot pass the file to the objects->update function. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Please check the link :- https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/mv

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I need Python for the gsutil tool which unfortunately isn't installed on the server. So it's not possible to rename a file with the google api php client? This seems a bit strange to me as it is possible to upload files to the storage with the php client.

Comment: Are you running your app on Google App Engine? If so, you should be able to rename the object directly using rename(): https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/advanced#php_filesystem_functions_support_on_google_cloud_storage

Comment: It seems that update(...) method updates only the metadata's object (like: Content-Type, Content-Encoding, etc)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, it seems I cannot directly rename a file (please correct me if I'm wrong), I could only update the metadata. I managed to get it to work by copying the file to a new filename/destination and then delete the old file. I successfully used $storageService->objects->copy and $storageService->objects->delete for this. This doesn't feels right but at least it works.

Comment: That is correct (copy + delete). There is no atomic rename/move operation.

Comment: @user2849119: jterrace is correct that you cannot perform the rename/move operation on the php client library. However you can perform the list, copy,delete,insert etc operation.

It seems a nice feature request, its better you can also file a feature request on PIT  https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/

Comment: Any idea how I copy a folder? I am defining the bucket (same for source and destination) and then defining the source folder, and then the destination folder. However I get a 404 not found error

Answer (score 0):

As this is not very well documented with google, here a basic example:

```
//RENAME FILE ON GOOGLE CLOUD STORAGE (GCS)

//Get client and auth token (might vary depending on the way you connect to gcs – here with laravel framework facade)
//DOC: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/json-api-php-samples
//DOC: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts
//Laravel Client: https://github.com/pulkitjalan/google-apiclient 
//Get google client
$gc = \Google::getClient();
//Get auth token if it is not valid/not there yet
if($gc->isAccessTokenExpired())
    $gc->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion();
//Get google cloud storage service with the client
$gcStorageO = new \Google_Service_Storage($gc);

//GET object at old position ($path)
//DOC: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/get
$oldObj = $gcStorageO->objects->get($bucket, $path);

//COPY desired object from old position ($path) to new position ($newpath)
//DOC: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/copy
$gcStorageO->objects->copy(
    $bucket, $path, 
    $bucket, $newpath,
    $oldObj
);

//DELETE old object ($path)
//DOC: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/delete
$gcStorageO->objects->delete($bucket, $path);
```

Comment: @SterlingArcher I have added better code documentation. Does that help?

Comment: @SterlingArcher It's simple a copy and then a remove. It's a way to simulate the rename.

Answer (score 0):

I found that when using gcutils in conjunction with PHP, you can execute pretty much every php file command on app engine. Copy, delete, check if file exists.

```
if(file_exists("gs://$bucket/{$folder}/$old_temp_file")){

        $old_path = "gs://$bucket/{$folder}/$old_temp_file";
        $new_permanent_path = "gs://$bucket/{$folder}/$new_permanent_file";

        copy($old_path, $new_permanent_path);  

        unlink($old_path);

    }
```